# make many count () in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data set of call customer, I want to make count () to know:
Total number of calls for each customer 
Total duration of call for each customer 
Total of locations the customer he where in

This my data:

```
Phone no. - Duration In minutes - Location

1111            3                     88
2222            4                     33
3333            4                     4
1111            7                     55
3333            9                     4
3333            7                     3
```

the result of query:

```
phone no- Total number of records -Total duration of calls- Total of location

1111              2                          10                   2
2222              1                           4                   1
3333              3                           20                  2
```

Comment: group by, count, sum etc.

Comment: This seems like a basic `group by` query.  What is the issue?

Comment: Thank you all for helping ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost similar to fthiella answer. Try like this

```
select PhoneNo,
count(*) as TotalNumberOfRecords, 
sum(DurationInMinutes) as TotalDurationOfCalls,
count(distinct location) as TotalOfLocations from yourtablename
group by PhoneNo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GROUP BY query with basic aggregated functions, like COUNT(), SUM() and COUNT(DISTINCT) like this:

```
select phone_no, count(*), sum(duration), count(distinct location)
from tablename
group by phone_no
```

Answer (score 0):

answer for your question is

```
select Phone no,count(Duration In minutes),sum(Duration In minutes),count(distinct Location) from Tablename group by Phone no order by Phone no;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made temporary table for testing and it gives same output as you mention. look following query :

```
declare @TEMP table (phone_no int, duration int, location int)
insert into @temp values(1111,3,88),(2222,4,33),(3333,4,4),(1111,7,55),(3333,9,4),(3333,7,3)

select phone_no, count(*), sum(duration), count(distinct location)
from @TEMP
group by phone_no
```

you just can consider this query :

```
select phone_no, count(*), sum(duration), count(distinct location)
from @TEMP
group by phone_no
```